# Android: Activity wait until boolean condition

Tags: java, android

Given a boolean condition `isCondition` which will be updated by an asynchronous task, how can I make an Android `Activity` wait on this condition without blocking execution?

In normal java, using `Thread.sleep()` inside a loop works well enough, but I am unsure of how safe this is to use in Android.

The asynchronous task that updates the `isCondition` variable is in an external library, which is abstracted away from my control. I would not like this endless poll to block or slow execution of other tasks, or take up too much processing, but rather release execution to other threads that may need to run.

(I am using API 25)

Comment: I would like it to keep polling the condition until it is `true`, at which point it should continue execution as per normal. However, I would not like this endless poll to block or slow execution of other tasks, or take up too much processing, but rather release execution to other threads that may need to run.

Comment: Thread.sleep on any thread but the main thread or the AsyncTask thread is fine.  Using it on the main thread will cause the app to freeze, using it on the AsyncTask thread will starve other AsyncTasks.  But on its own thread is ok.  Its rarely the right thing to do though, its generally better to wait on a lock like a semaphore and signal it when the condition is true.  If you want to notify the main thread, the best thing to do is post a message to a Handler made on the main thread when the condition is true.

Comment: I think when the `isCondition` variable is true in the asynchronous task then you can broadcast a message to the activity.

Comment: Thanks @GabeSechan. I think it will be in the main thread. I'm thinking about using a thread to poll the condition, and then signal the main thread. Can you answer this with some code snippets on how to set up this thread and the signal please?

Comment: @SonTruong The problem is the asynchronous task itself is abstracted away from my control, so I cannot write code in there to signal the activity.

Comment: You mean from the activity you only have permission to read value `isCondition` variable.

Comment: @SonTruong The asynchronous task that updates the `isCondition` variable is in an external library

Comment: I think you cannot modify the external library which receives `isCondition` as a parameter (then modify it some point in the future). So in you activity you should spawn a thread that wait until `isCondition` is true then notify to your main thread to update activity.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179669/discussion-between-son-truong-and-aman-singh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not a good idea to pause/sleep main UI thread because it would stop all UI interaction processing, often triggered **"Application Not Responding" (ANR)** dialog.

you could implement `AsyncTask` class, and get `isCondition` value in `onPostExecute` method, then do something as you want. [official doc gives a good example](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask)
.

**Edit**
  notice your comments, you could run a [TimerTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask) to query `isCondition` value repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

we can:

```
// 1. use an callback interface:
public interface ICompleted{
    void execute(boolean succeeded);
}

// 2. pass an instance to asynchronous task runner
asynchTaskRunner (new ICompleted() {
        @Override
        public void execute(boolean succeeded) {
              ...
        }
    });

// 3. run the callback from asynch task when nedded
iCompleted.execute(true or false);
```

Good luck )

Answer (score 0):

If I use Thread or Handler + `while(true)`, it will cause ui stuck, so I use following code, `cancel()` is important, it will prevent run timertask again

```
public static void waitUntil(final Activity ctx, final WaitUntil wu) {
        new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ctx.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (wu.cond()) {
                            wu.todo();
                            cancel();
                        }
                    }
                });

            }
        }, 1000);
    }
```

And WaitUntil interface

```
public interface WaitUntil {
    boolean cond();
    void todo();
}
```